# Using Django templates with Angular JS

Tags: django, angularjs

I'm in the process of porting my website front-end to Angular JS. The backend is based on Django.

I initially planned to develop a restful API for Angular to fetch data from backend.

However, I've found that the easiest way would be to generate partials templates in Django. Is there any disadvantage of this approach that I'm missing?

Currently I don't plan use any data binding.

Comment: so to only show the rendered template with Angular? if yes, then this kinda destroys the whole point of Angular.

Comment: The template would be generated in Django only to pass data from backend more easily (it's not only about model data, but also eg. translations). 

The template will still contain Angular code. (The website will be single page application). Is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: There is no problem, but in that case you probably even don't need angular. I just don't see the use for it.

Can you tell more about angular code?

Comment: We decided to choose Angular to: have flexible front-end that adapts to mobile/desktops resolution nicely and to have a website that is SPA (no reloading done).
Is there easier way of doing this?

Comment: angular does no have anything related to adapting to mobile/desktop resolution, because it's only JS framework. You should probably use CSS framework like bootstrap, foundation or any other framework. For SPA it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you're side stepping one of the things Angular is spectacular at which is routing.

I've recently started creating a Django website which uses Angular Js and had a difficult time wrapping my head around how I would use django templates with angular templates.

To sum it up;

1. I created an app named band which has one page.
2. I setup Django rest framework to handle crud operation via a restful service for the band app.
3. I have one template for band, which does NOT use inheritance or anything since this interferes with routing. (I struggled with this a bit, maybe i'm off but below is my determination and direction)

The reason for the struggle is typically in Django you have a server side web framework.  Angular is a client side framework.  Django separates it's template directory from static directory content.  Your JavaScript angular files will be looking for template includes which it needs to find.  My particular production server setup uses Django (Mod-WSGI) to handle rendering the template while static content like images, js and css are rendered by NGINX.  Basically I just decided okay since Angular aims to be for SPA (single page applications)  I would simply have a django template for band which does not inherit from a base master page or anything like that and mostly leave up everything in that band template to be rendered and updated via angular.

Comment: I was considering separating Django templates from angular templates, but the website is new quite large and it would be much faster to reuse current Django templates / views (even thogh the design won't be as clean).

The website would still work as SPA with Angular routing, it's just that instead of pointing templateUrl to static Angular .html template, it will point to Django view that will generate the template eg:

'
when('/training/', {
        templateUrl: '/training/'
      }).
'

where www.site.com/training/ is path to a Django view